# «L’Est-e du Québec», «un film-e d’horreur»: des E euphoniques?

Tags: prononciation, euphonie, e-caduc

Si je désire parler de l’Est du Québec, avec mon accent québécois qui affrique les *du*, je prononce :

- lèss-dzu-kébèk

Je remarque que le T final du terme *Est* disparaît, même si je le conserve habituellement pour d’autres usages :

- Le soleil se lève à l’Es**t**
- Le vent d’Es**t** est plus rare que le vent d’Oues**t** au Québec.
- La 20 Es**t** se termine à Mont-Joli.

Quand j’ai travaillé dans l’Est du Québec et que j’écoutais la radio de Radio-Canada, les animateurs de cette chaîne habituellement réputée pour son bon français maintenaient l’affrication, mais prononçaient plutôt :

- lèst-e-dzu-kébèk

On y constatera l’ajout d’un E “béquille” pour faciliter la prononciation du T, un E que je qualifierais peut-être d’euphonique.

Je sais que le E caduc est souvent prononcé pour faciliter l’élocution de certaines rencontres de lettres, particulièrement pour la langue qui se veut plus soutenue, mais pas seulement pour elle :

- Rencontr**es** de lettres
- Bisqu**e** bisqu**e** rage !
- Ministr**e** de l’Intérieur
- Le cycl**e** de l’eau
- Je vous le montr**e**rais bien, mais...
- À vos risqu**es** et périls

Par ailleurs, la Banque de dépannage linguistique de l’OQLF mentionne [cette apparition possible d’un E](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4496) qui n’existe pas à l’écrit.

Est-ce une particularité du français “soutenu” à la québécoise, ou est-ce aussi commun un peu partout dans la Francophonie, possiblement aussi à d’autres niveaux de langue ?

Answer (score 4):

En appui à la question sans nécessairement s'appliquer à tous les cas présentés :

> [...] Pour une cause inconnue, depuis le dernier quart du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle,
>   un e tend à se réintroduire ou à s'introduire à la fin des mots,
>   surtout avant une pause : dans *Au revoir* [ɔʀvwᴀʀǝ] aussi bien que
>   dans *Je me fâche* [fᴀʃǝ]. Les locuteurs ont d'abord été des jeunes et
>   surtout des femmes. Cela était senti comme une affectation. Mais le
>   mouvement gagne. Comp. aussi en verlan (§ 192, d) [se ʀəlu] pour
>   *C'est lourd*. Voir F. Carton, dans [Hist. de la langue fr. 1945-2000](https://books.google.ca/books?id=3EJcAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Histoire%20de%20la%20langue%20fran%C3%A7aise%22%20%221945-2000%22%20f.%20carton&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22verlan%20e%22), pp. 52-55.
>
> [ [*Le bon usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=le%20bon%20usage&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=le%20bon%20usage&f=false), Grevisse et Goosse, Duculot, 14/16<sup>e</sup>,
>   § 29 *N.B.* 2) ]

On réfère à l'*[épithèse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pith%C3%A8se) vocalique* et au [*e épithétique*](https://www.persee.fr/doc/bec_0373-6237_2005_num_163_1_463619_t11_0265_0000_2) comme d'un phénomène d'*hyperliaison* (un document comme [*Pratiques de prononciation et enjeux sociaux. Approches post-variationnistes en sociophonétique du français de France*](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01910667/document), M. Candea, 2018, permettra sans doute de réfléchir plus avant sur ces sujets-là). Peut-être qu'il s'agit de ce genre de phénomène et dans ce cas ce ne serait pas propre au Québec mais bien le propre, par exemple, d'un locuteur de type « hyperfinaliste » selon certaines théories etc. (on lira avec intérêt la recherche de Candea, p. 82 et ss. ; 86, 97, 101 etc.).

Par ailleurs, vu le contexte qu'on a évoqué (le « style » de Radio-Canada), il pourrait peut-être s'agir dans certains cas d'[*hypercorrection*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection) (" s'exprimer de manière « trop correcte »") ; on retrouve parfois ce phénomène en [français québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#%C3%8Atre), entre autres.

Comment: Pour l'hypercorrection à Radio-Canada, je serais assez d'accord qu'on la trouve régulièrement (une petite demi-heure d'écoute récemment m’a offert de manière très soutenue «des cyber-z-attaques»). J'ose cependant croire que pour le nom de la région desservie par le poste, il y a recommendation explicite, je la suppose aussi réfléchie, du diffuseur. Merci pour les documents liés, aussi. Bien intéressants! Il est vrai que le français possède un «euh» de remplissage, qui apparaît un peu n’importe où dans la phrase, au hasard du besoin par le locuteur de rassembler et coordonner ses idées.

Comment: J'ai aussi pensé au e d'insistance, régulièrement utilisé par les enfants, parfois aussi par les adultes par plaisanterie. Les enfants y ont recours pour narguer *(c’est moi qui a trouvé-E c'est moi qui a trouvé-E)*, pour protester *(j'aime pas ça-E!)*, ou pour bien marquer la force d'un sentiment qu'ils ressentent *(Demain c'est Noël-E demain c'est Noël-E!)*.

Comment: En appui sur le site [Phonologie du Français Contemporain (PFC) : usages, variétés, structure](https://www.projet-pfc.net/) : [Comportement général du e caduc](https://www.projet-pfc.net/le-projet-pfc-ef/le-francais-explique/le-e-muet-2/quest-ce-que-le-e-muet-2/)

Answer (score 3):

Ce phénomène de [ə] euphonique n'est pas limité au Québec. Je ne sais pas s'il est plus prononcé au Québec qu'ailleurs, mais il existe aussi en France.

En règle générale, en français, on n'aime pas les syllabes qui se terminent par une consonne. Certaines consonnes sont plus acceptables que d'autres : un [ʁ] passe facilement en fin de syllabe, un [s] ou un [t] beaucoup moins. Deux consonnes en fin de syllabe, c'est vraiment difficile. Quand c'est possible, on rejette la ou les consonnes au début de la syllabe suivante. Par exemple, pour prononcer l'expression « d'est en ouest », on a tendance à découper les syllabes ‹dès-ten-nouest› ou ‹dè-sten-nouest›. Mais dans « l'est du … », un [t] suivi d'un [d], ce n'est pas prononçable.

Une solution possible est de sauter le [t] (il se fait assimiler par le [d]) : ‹lès-du›. Évidemment c'est très relâché.

Lorsqu'un mot se termine par une consonne (ou une suite de consonnes) difficile suivi d'un e muet, cela incite à prononcer ce e, même dans les dialectes où le e muet est en général muet. Et quand il n'y a pas de e muet, on peut en inventer un. Du coup, la prononciation ‹lès-t(e)-du› est posible, avec un [ə] très peu marqué, un vrai [schwa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) et non une [voyelle moyenne centrale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_centrale)).

(See also [Cliticization of “je” in spoken French: which syllable gets the /ʒ/ sound?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/cliticization-of-je-in-spoken-french-which-syllable-gets-the-%ca%92-sound/8298#8298), written in English, where I discuss the same phenomenon.)